# Where do programs that leave The Matrix go?

Tags: the-matrix

In *The Matrix Revolutions*, we are introduced to [The Trainman](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/The_Trainman), a mysterious exile that works for [The Merovingian](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/The_Merovingian). He created and operates the [Mobil Avenue](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Mobil_Avenue), a sort of "bubble" Matrix that runs outside the normal Matrix, where he is "God".

Through Mobil Avenue, exile programs can be smuggled into The Matrix, and programs due to be deleted can be smuggled *out*. It's easy to imagine something being put *into* The Matrix. It's much more difficult to imagine something getting *out* if it doesn't have somewhere to go, such as a physical body.

In the case of Smith (who got out in a different but similar fashion), he took over the body of an actual human. But in the case of exile programs getting out, where do they go? What do they expect to happen after they get out? Is this ever discussed in any material, or by the Wachowskis elsewhere?

Comment: They go to the Recycling Bin?

Comment: Not a definative answer so I'll put it as a comment: But in the Mobil Avenue link in your question it does state that "Mobil Avenue station (or Mobil Ave) is a separate virtual world controlled by the the Trainman as a smuggling portal for exile programs to get into the Matrix, and for **programs inside the Matrix to be smuggled into the machine world**. " So they go somewhere into the machine world... as for where that is specifically, that doesn't appear to be explained. It's possible the programs are merged into programming of specific robots, or other sub systems that run 01.

Comment: That's what I was trying to get at in my question. Once they've left The Matrix and got to the real world... then what? It feels to me like the fish in the tank in Finding Nemo. They dirtied the tank, got in the little baggies, rolled out the window, over the road, into the harbour, and..... ?

Comment: Given that there's no referenced link, I suspect the wiki has overreached itself. There might be some instances in the Matrix Online game (where all sorts of wackiness occurred) but I can't think of a single example in the films, webcomics or Animatrix shorts where a program is exiled from the Matrix and travels into the Machine World.

Answer (score 5):

Sati is a perfect example of a rogue program. She was created by her parents out of love and has no purpose. After managing to temporarily hide her *somewhere* for a short while, they're forced to accept that without a purpose, her code will be inevitably returned to the Mainframe. Rather than accepting that fate, they deal with the Merovingian to hide her inside the Matrix.

The converse doesn't happen. Simply put, and with the exception of Smith, **there are no examples of a Matrix-based program scheduled for termination hiding out in the Machine World,** only [Machine World-based programs hiding in the Matrix](https://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/matrix/images/1/18/Sati.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20080617002344) and Matrix-based programs (those that refuse to return to the Machine Mainframe) dealing with the Merovingian to hide out in the Matrix, known as [Exiles](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/The_Twins).

---

One assumes that there are places where machines can congregate, socialise and do business in the Machine World (or else how would Rama-Kandra and Kamala have met and fallen in love or arranged to travel into the Matrix to meet with the Merovingian) but these are more likely to be lobbies rather than actual accomodations.